# How can I access public static main() of class in another file?

Tags: php, oop

I have a file named GetCampaigns.php having class GetCampaigns. This class includes public static main method. I want to return the result of this function in another file. Tried several ways but unable to fetch result in another file. I am bit new to OOP so please help me through this.

GetCampaigns.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright 2018 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

namespace Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use GetOpt\GetOpt;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentNames;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V14\GoogleAdsClient;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V14\GoogleAdsClientBuilder;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V14\GoogleAdsException;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V14\GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V14\Errors\GoogleAdsError;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V14\Services\GoogleAdsRow;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V14\Services\SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest;
use Google\ApiCore\ApiException;
use Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenInterface;

/** This example gets all campaigns. To add campaigns, run AddCampaigns.php. */
class GetCampaigns
{
    private const CUSTOMER_ID = 1234567890; // added dummy customer id

    public static function main()
    {
        // Either pass the required parameters for this example on the command line, or insert them
        // into the constants above.
        $options = (new ArgumentParser())->parseCommandArguments([
            ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID => GetOpt::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT
        ]);

        // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile('path to\google_ads_php.ini')->build();

        // Construct a Google Ads client configured from a properties file and the
        // OAuth2 credentials above.
        $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
            ->fromFile()
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
            // We set this value to true to show how to use GAPIC v2 source code. You can remove the
            // below line if you wish to use the old-style source code. Note that in that case, you
            // probably need to modify some parts of the code below to make it work.
            // For more information, see
            // https://developers.devsite.corp.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/php/gapic.
            ->usingGapicV2Source(true)
            ->build();

        try {
            self::runExample(
                $googleAdsClient,
                $options[ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID] ?: self::CUSTOMER_ID
            );
        } catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
            printf(
                "Request with ID '%s' has failed.%sGoogle Ads failure details:%s",
                $googleAdsException->getRequestId(),
                PHP_EOL,
                PHP_EOL
            );
            foreach ($googleAdsException->getGoogleAdsFailure()->getErrors() as $error) {
                /** @var GoogleAdsError $error */
                printf(
                    "\t%s: %s%s",
                    $error->getErrorCode()->getErrorCode(),
                    $error->getMessage(),
                    PHP_EOL
                );
            }
            exit(1);
        } catch (ApiException $apiException) {
            printf(
                "ApiException was thrown with message '%s'.%s",
                $apiException->getMessage(),
                PHP_EOL
            );
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the example.
     *
     * @param GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient the Google Ads API client
     * @param int $customerId the customer ID
     */
    // [START get_campaigns]
    public static function runExample(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient, int $customerId)
    {
        $googleAdsServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient();
        // Creates a query that retrieves all campaigns.
        $query = 'SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name, metrics.impressions, metrics.clicks, metrics.conversions, metrics.ctr, metrics.average_cpc, metrics.cost_micros FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id';


        // Issues a search stream request.
        /** @var GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator $stream */
        $stream = $googleAdsServiceClient->searchStream(
            SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest::build($customerId, $query)
        );

        $campaign_details_array = array();

        // Iterates over all rows in all messages and prints the requested field values for
        // the campaign in each row.
        foreach ($stream->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
            /** @var GoogleAdsRow $googleAdsRow */
            
            $campaign_details_array[] = array('campaign_id' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getId(), 
                'campaign_name' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getName(),
                'impressions' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getImpressions(),
                'clicks' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getClicks(),
                'conversions' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getConversions(),
                'ctr' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getCtr(),
                'average_cpc' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getAverageCpc(),
                'cost_micros' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getCostMicros()
            );
        }

        // print_r($campaign_details_array); // printing the array in the result
        return $campaign_details_array;
    }
    // [END get_campaigns]
}

// GetCampaigns::main(); // works fine when initialised here

?>
```

campaign-details.php

```
<?php
  
  require('google-ads-php/GetCampaigns.php');

  $data = GetCampaigns::main();

  print_r($data);

?>
```

GetCampaigns.php lies project/google-ads-php/GetCampaigns.php directory. campaign-details.php lies in project/campaign-details.php directory.

Shows Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "GetCampaigns" not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\campaign-details.php:5

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using namespaces. You need to include namespaces when accessing a class. Try instead:

```
Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns::main();
```

Comment: Thanks now I can access the class method without errors. But when I call function it doesn't return value. But if result is in print_r() then it gets printed.

`print_r($campaign_details_array); // printing the array in the result
// return $campaign_details_array; `

gets result in campaign-details.php

Comment: I didn't understand you. If you run the `GetCampaigns::main()` it shouldn't return anything as it only prints data. The `runExample` method has a return statement which is called in `main` method and not stored in any variable.